# Model attribute contains collection of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, hstore

**I have main model Page, which is container.
The page can have some to-do lists, notes, files and discussions. The idea is to have them in special order.**

```
Page.last.container # [Todolist_obj, Note_obj, File_obj, Note_obj, Discussion_obj, File_obj, File_obj]
```

- So I came to approach to use Mongodb
- Or I also thought about using Postgres with hstore, but don't know will it help or not
- Or maybe just any database and deserialize all objects when getting page, and serialize objects when saving
- Or I can make superclass Item and inherit all containing objects from it using MTI and make Page has many relationship.

**So I don't know which way is the best?**

**or perhaps there is a better way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [acts_as_list](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_list) for implementing sortable objects very successfully. Additionally, i would abstract the elements of a page into a separate model, here called `PageElement`.

I think there is no need to switch to a NoSQL database (although i have nothing against this approach). Here is a rough sketch of what i'm thinking:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :page_elements, :order => 'position'
  has_many :todo_lists,  :through => :page_elements, :source => :element, :source_type => 'TodoList'
  has_many :notes,       :through => :page_elements, :source => :element, :source_type => 'Note'
  has_many :files,       :through => :page_elements, :source => :element, :source_type => 'File'
  has_many :discussions, :through => :page_elements, :source => :element, :source_type => 'Discussion'
end

class PageElement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  belongs_to :element, :polymorphic => true
  acts_as_list :scope => :page
end

class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :page_element, :as => :element
  has_one :page, :through => :page_elements 
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :page_element, :as => :element
  has_one :page, :through => :page_elements 
end

class File < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :page_element, :as => :element
  has_one :page, :through => :page_elements 
end

class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :page_element, :as => :element
  has_one :page, :through => :page_elements 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, So that's the way using MTI. Why others are not so good for you? Or to be correct, why you prefer this way instead of others?

Comment: I would *personally* stick with the MTI approach because a) it is database agnostic and b) it's the only approach that i have already implemented myself. I simply happen to not like NoSQL databases that much but this is just personal preference. My approach is surely not the only viable solution to this problem.