# Best way for todo list with any objects type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to create a todo list with any objects type. Objects that will be part of the list: Diet, Prescription and VeterinaryConsult.

Per hour i made: Keep the object class on object_type column, and when i will get the object, use the .send(TodoItem.x.object_type) method. This is the best way? I thought to use serialize option, but i don't how.

And for this, i create this structure:

---

**Diet**(id: integer, name: string, todo_item_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

```
class Diet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todo_item
end
```

---

**Prescription**(id: integer, name: string, todo_item_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

```
class Prescription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todo_item
end
```

---

**TodoItem**(id: integer, name: string, done_date: date, is_done: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, object_type: string)

```
class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :diet
  has_one :prescription

  def related
    self.send(self.object_type)
  end
end
```

---

On controllers i do:

```
class PrescriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :create_todo_item, only: [:create]
  def create
    @prescription = Prescription.new(prescription_params)
    @prescription.todo_item = @todo_item
    ...
  end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def create_todo_item
    @todo_item = TodoItem.new(object_type: params[:controller].singularize)
    @todo_item.save
  end
end
```

---

*Sorry for my poor english :|*

Comment: I want to associate more object types on the future, withou creating new relation for each class...

Comment: There is no way of creating further associations without explicitly declaring the relationship in the models.

Comment: I have recently answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029659/model-attribute-contains-collection-of-object/17031165#17031165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try a different approach:

Diet.rb

```
has_many :todo_items, as: :todoable
after_create :create_todo_item

def create_todo_item
  todo_items.create
end
```

Prescription.rb

```
has_many :todo_items, as: :todoable
after_create :create_todo_item

def create_todo_item
  todo_items.create
end
```

and on every other model you need todos you can use the above code

In TodoItem.rb all you have to do is

```
belongs_to :todoable, polymorphic: true
```

And create the fields on TodoItem todoable_type and todoable_id

Looks a lot better IMO. Even this way it is possible to further refactoring it creating a module "todoable" and load it on every model you need, but it is a next step

Comment: Yeah Anezio, i do this and i use concerns to make a method ho create thee todo_item every new object ;) Thnks!

Comment: Nice! But I think you could replace this `TodoItem.create(item_type: self.class.name, item_id: self.id)` to this `todo_item.create`. Polymorphic associations automatically sets the values for type and id. Take a look in the documentation here on how it works http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations